# Linux, mmap'ing IOMMU/SMMU registers to userspace

Tags: linux, mmap

I am working on a register dump utility for debugging.
Just out of curiosity, In Linux, can we mmap the SMMU/IOMMU registers
to userspace ? 
I get the below error, when I try to mmap my SMMU/IOMMU address space

"Error mapping physical memory: Cannot allocate memory"

**EDIT :**

The error was related to mmap'ing memory more than 4Gb on a 32 bit machine, which obviously fails. But the question still stands ..

Can I map SMMU/IOMMU controller registers using mmap ?

Answer (score 0):

I read  from  [here](http://www.embedded.com/design/operating-systems/4401769/Device-drivers-in-user-space)

> The mmap() call allows the user application to map a physical device
>   address range one page at a time or a contiguous range of physical
>   memory in multiples of page size.

So SMMU/IOMMU controller registers can be mapped using mmap.

Comment: Could you fix the link, does not seem the one you intended to add

Comment: @jarvis1729  fixed, please check